# What do you call someone who breaks down every detail of a job?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What do you call a boss or someone who breaks down every detail of a job?

Comment: You need to provide more context for how this word will be used. It could be a micro-manager.

Comment: A "detail person".

Comment: *analytical*...

Answer (score 2):

Micro-manager. To [*micromanage*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/micromanage) means:

> to manage especially with excessive control or attention to details

[Merriam-Webster]

If it's the person doing things himself he's just pedantic.

Comment: That is not true, micro manager is a term for someone who is giving too many instructions to his workers.

Comment: @Chris in other words, 'breaks down every detail of the job'?

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. Your answer was automatically flagged as low quality for its length. Please try to follow the format when you answer a question next time. Good luck.

Comment: Yes but the question was "What do you call a boss or someone who breaks down every detail of a job?", you can have a meticulous boss who is not a micro manager, micro manager is the one who is always breathing down your neck.

Comment: micro manage, was the word I could not remember, because of  TBI.

Answer (score 0):

**Rigorous**

> (of a rule, system, etc.) strictly applied or adhered to: ‘rigorous controls on mergers’

**Scrupulous**

> (of a person or process) careful, thorough, and extremely attentive
>   to details: ‘the research has been carried out with scrupulous
>   attention to detail’

Both from Oxford English dictionary.